# Error compiling c++ tutorial (programmingHelp.org)

Tags: c++, g++

I am following tutorials from [youtube](http://youtu.be/vz1O9nRyZaY). It seems I have encountered an error I can't resolve by myself. The goal is to create a class called BMI, which takes users weight name and height and prints them out..

I'm trying to compile it using g++, and I suspect I'm not doing it right. Usually I just do g++ filename.cpp, as I should in this case?

The tutorial is originally in that Microsoft ....thing, I don't know it's name. Sorry

Thank you, the code is attached below.

The error

```
/tmp/ccRcewk3.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `BMI::BMI()'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `BMI::getWeight() const'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `BMI::getHeight() const'
Main.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `BMI::getName() const'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x14f): undefined reference to `BMI::~BMI()'
Main.cpp:(.text+0x184): undefined reference to `BMI::~BMI()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "BMI.h"

using namespace std;

/**************************************************/
int main()
{
  string name;
  int height;
  double weight;

  cout << "Enter your name: ";
  cin >> name;

  cout << "Enter your height (cm): ";
  cin >> height;

  cout << "Enter your weight (kg): ";
  cin >> weight;

  BMI Student_1;

  cout << endl << "Patient name: " << Student_1.getName() << endl <<
    "Height: " << Student_1.getHeight() << endl <<
    "Weight: " << Student_1.getWeight() << endl;
  return 0; 
}
/**************************************************/
```

BMI.h

```
// Header ==> Function Declarations

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// tu ide klasa
#ifndef BMI_H
#define BMI_H

class BMI
{
 public:
  //Default Constructor
  BMI();

  //Overload Constructor
  BMI(string, int, double);

  //Destructor
  ~BMI();

  // Accessor functions
  string getName() const;
  // // // returns name of patient

  int getHeight() const;
  // // // returns height of patient

  double getWeight() const;
  // // // returns weight of patient


 private:
  // member variables
  string newName;
  int newHeight;
  double newWeight;

};

#endif
```

BMI.cpp:

```
//Function definitions

#include "BMI.h"

// to access function inside a class

BMI::BMI()
{
  newHeight = 0;
  newWeight = 0.0;
}

BMI::BMI(string name, int height, double weight)
{
  newName = name;
  newHeight = height;
  newWeight = weight;
}

BMI::~BMI()
{

}

string BMI::getName() const
{
  return newName;
}

int BMI::getHeight() const
{
  return newHeight;
}

int BMI::getWeight() const
{
  return newWeight;
}
```

edit:
OK, thanks everyone, I got part of the problem solved. However, you got me a little confused with editing, so I will do over.

It seems that the original code is not working, and I feel it should. Anyway, the edited code from the question doesn't work either.

So, I will try to do it again. But thank you, now I know how to compile. :)

edit2:
Everything is working now, thank you very much.

Comment: Try `g++ Main.cpp BMI.cpp`. The problem is you need to link them both together; my GCC is rusty but I think that'll compile them both and link them into an executable called Main. Or you can compile them both with `-c` then run g++ on the resulting two `.o` files. But you should look into writing yourself a Makefile too.

Comment: `g++ -o MyProgram Main.cpp BMI.cpp` should do the trick.

Comment: In fact I'd look into using an IDE anyway. You can get free versions of Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ or Visual Studio Express (that Microsoft thing) that should all make this easy for you, and include integrated editing help and debuggers etc. that will help you in the long run as you move onto more complex stuff.

Comment: OK, I'm looking into this. I agree IDE-s are usefull, but I know too little to use them. In other words, it's better to suffer now then later :) Thank you all, I will update

Comment: @mvw why are you making fixes (which are probably part of the problem solution) inside the question?

Comment: @poncha: I wanted to keep him going with a running program, after the compile and link issues (which is his core problem) are fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile the main.cpp into Main.o and BMI.cpp into BMI.o.

```
g++ -c Main.cpp
g++ -c BMI.cpp
```

Then you need to link both object files into one executable (and link to the Standard C++ lib)

```
g++ -o myprog Main.o BMI.o -lstdc++
```

Run the example with

```
./myprog
```

There seem to be more bugs, I have no time to fix, please continue yourself. :-)

```
[marc@quadfork ~/test]$./myprog
Enter your name: foo
Enter your height (cm): 23
Enter your weight (kg): 2

Patient name:
Height: 0
Weight: 0
```

Comment: See the comments above or "info gcc" on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

your function return noting in your BMI.cpp
try with this.

```
string BMI::getName() const
{
  return newName;
}

int BMI::getHeight() const
{
  return newHeight;
}

double BMI::getWeight() const
{
  return newWeight;
}
```

Comment: While the user will have this as a problem, this has nothing to do with the current error.

Comment: You are right, the programm has several bugs.. I try to fix them in the question.

Comment: There was also a typo in the cout statement. (Additional "b" or so)